# Yii2 GridView value call to a model function

Tags: gridview, yii2

In my User model I have a function:

```
public function getRole() {
    if ($this->role == self::ROLE_USER) {
        return "user";
    } else if ($this->role == self::ROLE_ADMIN) {
        return "admin";
    }

    return "unassigned";
}
```

In the GridView I'd like to call it, but can't figure out how in Yii2, the old Yii way doesn't seem to work:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'role',
    'filter' => false,
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => '$model->getRole()',
],
```

I don't want use an anonymous function:

```
'value' => function($model) {
    switch($model->role) {
        case 10:
            return "user";
            break;
        case 90;
            return "admin";
            break;
        default;
            return "unassigned";
            break;
    }
},
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use an anonymous function? This is the preferred way.

Comment: because it's code duplication as I'm using `getRole` in other instances

Comment: What mean it's code duplication and .. ...  ? please explain better your comment

Comment: in the anonymous function I was checking and returning the role string, which means both function did the same thing.

Comment: I Don't undetstand  In the anonymous function my answer  call the $model->getRole()

Comment: Yes but mine didn't, I updated the question. I was checking for the role right in it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a closure (anonymous function)

```
[
  'attribute' => 'role',
  'filter' => false,
  'format' => 'raw',
   'value' => function ($model) {
       return  $model->getRole();
   },
],
```

THe setting of the value attribute could be done with  string or  a anonymous  function (no other)

> $value      -   public property
>
> An anonymous function or a string that is used
>   to determine the value to display in the current column.
>
> If this is an anonymous function, it will be called for each row and
>   the return value will be used as the value to display for every data
>   model.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$value-detail

If the value required is related to the $model instance the anonymous function is the  only possibility

Comment: But... but... it's anonymous function you said you don't want to use...

Comment: I have added   brief explanation from Yii2  doc.. seem that closure  is the (only) way for this kind of result  ..

Comment: It is but apparently @keeg confused it with something else.

Comment: @Bizley   I think you're right .. I think the  OP is confusing the closure with something else .

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do this is using magic methods. For example:

```
'columns' => [
   ...
   'role'
   ...
]
```

And with your magic method in your model:

```
public function getRole(){return 'admin';}
```

It will be enough to render it. Easy, and there are a lot of options. You can know more [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview#$columns-detail).